# how To add subview in table view using story board

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am using story board. I want to add a subview when a element is selected on table view.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arr count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *cellvalue = [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text=cellvalue;

    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i am new in ios development .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards are useful to show your app flow.Hence there is no point in adding a view without showing the flow in story board.

storyboard segues(connection between on view to another) are three types,push,modal and custom. If you don't want to do a push or present as a modal, you can create your own custom segue by over riding the perform method of `UIStoryboardSegue`.

```
 - (void)perform
{
// Add your own code here.

    [[self sourceViewController] addChildViewController:[self destinationViewController]];
}
```

[Developer reference for custom segues](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html).

Comment: If can trying adding it as a subview in the perform method.

Comment: i want to go next view for detail form my present view that have a table view , then i select a row , now subview (detail) vies should be open .  thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want ti make it straight from StoryBoard you need to Ctrl-drag from the table view cell (prototype cell) to the destination view.

Comment: yes i have already done it , bot not working . how can i do this programatically . may i use didselect row index path ??

Comment: I guess this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1845/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-2) will solve your problem!