# navigation from tableview to another view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I am working in a table view app using story board  . I want to perform event on selection

of cell in table view . So when I select a cell element , a next view(detailview) should be

open for displaying further details .

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 {  
    self.dv = [[Detail alloc]initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:nil];


    dv.dic = [self.arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    [self.view addSubview:dv.view];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how To add subview in table view using story board](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075389/how-to-add-subview-in-table-view-using-story-board)

Comment: Don't post the same question twice.

Comment: caught red-handed by @occulus hh ;)

Comment: Instead of giving answer on this thread.Please do on original.Differnt thread for duplicate question is waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the storyboard drag a segue from the viewcontroller icon at the bottom of your view to the next viewcontroller you want to segue to.  Make sure that your view is embedded in a navigation controller.  Press the arrow that appears between your tableviewcontroller and the target view controller and make sure you label it with a segue identifier.  Then in the method you are describing make sure they selected the correct index path with an if statement and write

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"theNameOfYourIdentifierFromTheStoryboard"];
```

That being said, I think that there is a large body of information you should research.

Read this: http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/ as a start.

Answer (score 1):

Instead try this:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{  
       self.dv = [[Detail alloc]initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:nil];


        dv.dic = [self.arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


       [self presentViewController:dv animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And if you want to dismiss use this code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: when i select row it not perform any event and app is crashed :(

Comment: Try self.dv = [[Detail alloc]init] instead of self.dv = [[Detail alloc]initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:nil];

Comment: He's using storyboard so he doesn't have nib files. Use dv = [storybard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"]; and set the storyboard ID to "DetailViewController" for your detail view.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a navigation controller and when selecting a row, push the detail view into it.

To create navigation controller: selected the tableview controller and go Editor / Embed in / Navigation Controller.

Then do:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    // dv = [Detail alloc] initWithNibName:@"Detail" bundle:nil];
    dv = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
    dv.dic = [self.arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dv];
}
```

The commented line is if you're not using storyboard.

Or you can do as Abdullah suggested, but implement a dismiss button with

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: local declaration of dv hides instance  variable . pls suggest me .

Comment: Edited the answer to fix the issue, however I wouldn't recommend creating an instance variable, instead creating a variable when the user selects a row. Explanation: If the user doesn't select any row, the instance variable is still created, but not used, thus being used memory without reason.